# Older Exchange calendar disappear in Android Calendar, but not in Apple Calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, exchange

I have an Exchange account for my email and calendar, which I use on my Mac in the default Calendar desktop app, and on my phone in the Android Calendar app. On the phone, older items (last week and older) disappear, on the Mac they stay, so it looks like this is not an Exchange problem.

I want to see my old appointments on the phone, back to the first appointment ever. It's just text, so it can't be that much.

**Why do these older items disappear and how can I bring them back?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open system settings
- Goto Users and accounts
- Click on the exchange account
- Click on Account settings
- Click on the settings button next to the account name

Now you see all settings for this account.

- Scroll down
- Click on "past items synchronisation"
- Change this to all past items
- Click the back button till you're out of the settings

NB: I translated "past items synchronisation", so the actual English name for this might be different, but I think it's clear what I mean. If you have the correct naming, then please comment here.